# How to show this sequence of functions weakly converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

$X = C[0,1]$. $$x_n(t) =
\begin{cases}
nt,  & \text{for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n}$ } \\
2-nt, & \text{for $\frac{1}{n} \leq t \leq \frac{2}{n}$ }  \\
0, & \text{for $\frac{2}{n} \leq t \leq 1$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

I know $x_n$ doesn't tend to zero strongly, but I don't know how to show it tends to zero weakly in $L^{\infty}$.

**Added**: A sequence of $\{x_n\}$ in a normed linear space $X$ is said to converge weakly to $x$ if $$\lim_{n \to \infty}l(x_n) = l(x)$$ for every $l$ in $X'$(the dual of $X$, i.e. the collection of all continuous linear functionals.).

Comment: Weakly converge in what sense?

Comment: I guess he/she means $\langle x_n, f \rangle \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for any $f \in X$.

Comment: @RagibZaman: Fixed and sorry, I don't know there're more than one sense of weakly convergence.

Comment: Observe that $C[0, 1]\subset L^2([0,1])$, and $L^2([0,1])$ is a Hilbert space. We can now use the Riesz representation theorem (recall that the inner product in $L^2$ is given by $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{[0,1]}fg d\mu$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure). I should add that you haven't specified the norm on $C[0,1]$, so I am assuming the $L^2$ norm. If you want the uniform norm (i.e. the $L^\infty$ norm), then one needs a different approach.

Comment: @William: Thank you for your partial answer. It's still unclear to me what to do next. I saw a trick for $x_n$ as an orthonormal sequence is to appeal to Bessel's inequality. But I don't know how to deal with this case.

Comment: So, isn't it true that the $L^2$ norm of $x_n$ is $\frac{2}{3n}$, or did I miscalculate? If this is the norm, then $x_n\to 0$ in $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{L^2}$ and so I don't really see what your question is asking. It would make more sense to me if the question was about $L^1$ rather than $L^2$, because $\Vert x_n\Vert_{L^1}=1$ (and so don't converge in norm to zero), and also $L^\infty\cong (L^1)^*$.

Comment: @J.Loreaux Thank you for your comment. I thought the limit in $L^2$ should be unique which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that what you want to prove is weak convergence in $C[0,1]$ endowed with $L^{\infty}$ norm. Using Riesz representation, i.e. the dual of $C[0,1]$ can be identified with bounded Borel measures, we need only to take care of convergence $\int x_n d\mu \to 0$ for any measure $\mu$. But this is equivalent for the sequence $(x_n)$ to being uniformly bounded and pointwise convergent, via dominated convergence theorem.